# Como debugar código NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, aplicação-web

Em meus estudos iniciais no desenvolvimento para web com NODEJS tenho a seguinte dúvida: uma ferramenta para debugar códigos NODEJS em um sistema Web ?

Comment: VS Code + Extensão faz isso muito bem.

Comment: poderia compartilhar um passo-a-passo para configurar o ambiente ? Bem como estudo de caso !

Comment: Claro. https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging

Comment: Você pode dar uma olhada na IDE Visual Studio da Microsoft, ela possui um debugger imbutido que permite você pausar a execução e testar variáveis ao vivo. Segue links: Apresentação do VS Code
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=119e0lgol0s Download:
https://code.visualstudio.com/

Comment: Veja nesse link como configurar o VSCode para utilizar o debug de aplicações NodeJS. [Configurar Debug VSCode](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bVAhNaxBEjM)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
function facaalgumacoisa(a+b) {

        debugger;

        return a+b;

    }

    let test = 0;

    debugger;
```

na linha de comando digite `node inspect` `nomedoarquivo.js`

Answer (score 2):

Existem algumas opções para que você possa fazer isso...

Eu acho bacana utilizar `vs code` com extensões...

Caso queira aprender sobre javascript, node, react e react native, te recomendo dar uma olhada na rocket seat: https://skylab.rocketseat.com.br/